# NVMe RAID on Linux with AMD Ryzen Line-Up Possible?

Tags: linux, ssd, raid, nvme, amd-ryzen

I am planning on building an own Linux server (I am leaning towards Ubuntu) for different applications like my own Mail Server, Web Server, File Server, NAS, VPN etc.

I am planning on buying an AMD Ryzen 3 3100 and I want to attach 2 (two) M.2 PCIe 3.0 x4 1TB NVMe SSD's onto the motherboard either directly (if the board has two M.2 connectors with full PCIe 3.0 x4 lanes) or via a "controller card" where I put both SSD's into the controller card and the card into a x16 lane port (ASUS Hyper M.2 x16 Card V2). I haven't decided on the motherboard yet, as you can see because of this problem.

The reason for the 2 NVMe SSD's is redundancy which I want to establish by using RAID 1 on this server  but I can't seem to find any useful information regarding RAID on NVMe... only SATA. I want to boot my Ubuntu OS from those SSD's and not have a third hard drive for the OS. Is this even possible? I only encounter Threadripper manuals on the web to be able to do so but I rather stick to a motherboard that has the AM4-socket and especially the Ryzen line-up then the super expensive Threadripper line-up of CPU's.

So is this a fantasy or possible? :)

I will by the way not have any GPU and instead be managing the system "headless" by SSH with some GUI on my home computer, partially to have more PCIe lanes.

List of components that I currently am aiming on purchasing:

- Motherboard: 1x MSI B450M-A PRO MAX
- CPU:         1x AMD Ryzen 3 3100
- SSD:         2x Kingston A2000 M.2 1TB
- RAM:         1x Corsair Vengeance LPX DDR4 2666MHz 16GB

Is this server overkill or maybe not powerful enough in your opinion for the tasks mentioned in the beginning?

Incase this setup is possible, can this even be done when I encrypt the SSD's with Full Disk Encryption (FDE)?

Would love some of your input on this!

Comment: What makes you think there is a different in setting up a RAID when you use NVMe drives instead of SATA drives?  The only possible reason it would make a difference is if the RAID controller is the SATA controller.

Comment: Because no one mentions it anywhere and only talks about SATA connections and the SATA bus which leads me to believe the exact thing you said in your second sentence. I didn't encounter the extra comment "This applies to NVMe SSD's aswell." anywhere. But reading your comment gives me some hope!! :) @Ramhound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no driver that supports AMD-RAID with NVMe drives. Only SATA is supported through rcraid. So you will not be able to use hardware acceleration and caching for your RAID array.

You will only be able to set up a software raid array.